# JDBC PoolingDataSource vs PoolingDriver

Tags: apache, jdbc

With reference to apache commons dbcp, what is the difference between PoolingDataSource and PoolingDriver?  The source code states

"Note that this example is very similiar to the PoolingDriver example.  In fact, you could use the same pool in both a PoolingDriver and a PoolingDataSource"

However it does not explicit state the differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PoolingDriver implements the Driver interface, so you could use that wherever you need a java.sql.Driver.

And similarly , PoolingDataSource implements the DataSource interface.

(e.g. some frameworks need you to pass a reference to a Driver or DataSource , if you want them pooled you use one of PoolingDataSource or PoolingDriver -)